# Erro de contexto em método interno a classe que estende asynctask

Tags: android, asynctask

Olá,
Postei o código completo.
O erro de compilação ocorre na classe playmusic.
Obrigado pela atenção!

```
public class Agendador
{

        //Toolkit toolkit;
        Timer timer;

        public Agendador() {
            //  toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
            timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new RemindTask(),
                           0,        //initial delay
                           20*1000);  //subsequent rate
        }

        class RemindTask extends TimerTask {
            int numWarningBeeps = 3;
            public void run() {
                if (numWarningBeeps > 0) {
                    //toolkit.beep();
                    Log.v("mensagem","Execucao: " + Integer.toString(numWarningBeeps));
                    new PutMethodDemo().execute();
                    //System.out.println("Beep!");
                    numWarningBeeps--;
                } else {
                    //toolkit.beep(); 
                    //System.out.println("Time's up!");
                    //timer.cancel(); // Not necessary because
                    // we call System.exit
                    Log.v("mensagem"," fim " + Integer.toString(numWarningBeeps));
                    System.exit(0);   // Stops the AWT thread 
                    // (and everything else)
                }

            }
        }
```

}

```
public class PutMethodDemo extends AsyncTask<String , Void ,String>
{

//Declare uma variável de instância para o player
private MediaPlayer mp = null;


    HttpResponse response;
    String server_content = null;
    HttpClient client = getThreadSafeClient();


    public DefaultHttpClient getThreadSafeClient()  {

        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        ClientConnectionManager mgr = client.getConnectionManager();
        HttpParams params = client.getParams();
        client = new DefaultHttpClient(new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params,   mgr.getSchemeRegistry()), params);
        return client;
    } 




    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://www.consuladoportugalrjservicos.com/public_html/exec");

        Integer statusCode = doGet("http://consuladoportugalrj.org.br");    
        if(statusCode !=200)
        {
            Log.e("warn","codigo de erro "+Integer.toString(statusCode));
            return "err";
        }

        statusCode = doGet("http://www.consuladoportugalrjservicos.com/public_html/");
        if(statusCode !=200)
        {
            Log.e("warn","codigo de erro "+Integer.toString(statusCode));
            return "err";
        }

        //post

        List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("modulo", "modulo.login"));
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("acao", "login101"));
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("txtcpf", "02355180776"));
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("txtusuario","acastanheira2001@yahoo.com.br"));

        try
        {
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
        {
            Log.e("UnsupportedEncodingException",e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try
        {
            response = client.execute(post);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {

            Log.e("IOException",e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        // Getting the status code.
        statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        Log.e("Response_code  ", "" + statusCode);

        if(statusCode !=200)
        {
            Log.e("warn","codigo de erro "+Integer.toString(statusCode));
            return "err";
        }


        HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();


        try
        {
            server_content = readStream(httpEntity.getContent());
        }
        catch (UnsupportedOperationException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //post 2
        pairs.clear();
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("modulo", "modulo.servicos"));
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("acao", "servico990"));


        try
        {
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
        {       
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try
        {
            response = client.execute(post);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Getting the status code.
        statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        Log.e("Response_code  ", "" + statusCode);

        if(statusCode !=200)
        {
            Log.e("warn","codigo de erro "+Integer.toString(statusCode));
            return "err";
        }


        httpEntity = response.getEntity();

        try
        {
            server_content = readStream(httpEntity.getContent());
        }
        catch (UnsupportedOperationException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.v("server_content",  server_content);

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        if(s == null)
        {
        //procurar pelo texto rbtnhora
        if(server_content.contains("rbtnhora\" value=\"-1\""))
            Log.e("Response_agenda  ", "Agenda fechada " + s);
        else
        {
            Log.e("Response_agenda  ", "Agenda aberta " + s);
            //emite um som.
            playMusic();

        }

        }


    }
```

// Converting InputStream to String

```
    private String readStream(InputStream in) {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return response.toString();
    }


    //private HttpResponse doGet(String enderecoGet)
    private Integer doGet(String enderecoGet)
    {

        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(enderecoGet);

        try
        {
            response = client.execute(get);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {       
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        // Getting the status code.
        int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        Log.v("Response_source  ", "" + enderecoGet);
        Log.v("Response_code  ", "" + statusCode);  


        //return response;
        return statusCode;

    }   

public void playMusic() {

    //Se algum som ainda estiver a tocar pára-o
    releasePlayer();

    Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    MediaPlayer mp =  MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), notification);

 !!!!O ERRO ESTÁ NA LINHA ACIMA!!!


    //mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ulso);
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                //No final de tocar liberta o media player para poder ser novamente utilizado
                releasePlayer();
            }
        });

    //Toca o som
    mp.start();

}

//Método para libertar o media player
    private void releasePlayer() {
        if (mp != null) {
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
            mp = null;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: bom dia, voce poderia colocar o codigo inteiro por faovr?

Comment: Olá, postei o código completo. Agradeço antecipadamente pela sua atenção.

Comment: @LuizFernandoSalvaterra olá, postei o código completo. Agradeço antecipadamente pela sua atenção.